# How to pass the window through ipcRenderer.send()?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am building a multi-window application using Electron 12.0.0 and trying to use the latest defaults (nodeIntegration = false, contextIsolation = true).  I am trying to figure out how each renderer process is supposed to tell the main process which window is sending the IPC message.  I get an error (shown below) when I try to pass the `window` object as an argument to ipcRenderer.send() by doing something like this:

```
window.api.receive('save', () => {
  window.api.send('save-file', window, markdownView.value)
})
```

where window.api is defined in `preload.js` like this:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  "api",
  {
    send: (channel, ...args) => {
      const validChannels = [
        'save-file'
      ]
      if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args)
      }
    },
    receive: (channel, func) => {
      const validChannels = [
        'save',
        'file-opened',
        'file-saved'
      ]
      if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        // Strip off the event since it includes the sender
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Everything works fine until I try to invoke the Save menu item (which sends the `save` message to the renderer) and I get this following errors in the Console (of Developer Tools):

```
[Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated.                          renderer.js:9
 Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
(anonymous) @ renderer.js:9
(anonymous) @ VM76 preload.js:22
emit @ VM14 events.js:315
onMessage @ VM75 renderer_init.js:93

Uncaught Error: Uncaught Error: Uncaught Error: An object could not be cloned.
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (VM76 preload.js:22)
    at EventEmitter.emit (VM14 events.js:315)
    at Object.onMessage (VM75 renderer_init.js:93)
(anonymous) @ VM76 preload.js:22
emit @ VM14 events.js:315
onMessage @ VM75 renderer_init.js:93
```

Clearly, I am doing something wrong.  How do I accomplish this, preferably without turning on nodeIntegration or turning off contextIsolation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send complex objects like window references. I have a simple, 2-window app and the way I do it is to have a message format which includes a string identifying the "sender" (below). I've found the use of a messaging format very flexible and extensible.

If you don't want to go that far, you can send the [window ID](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winid-readonly) and use [BrowserWindow.fromId(id)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowfromidid) in `Main` to get the window reference.

---

**Renderer:**

```
let  arg = { event: "save-project", sender: "editor", data: editorJson };   
ipcRenderer.send('app-message', arg);
```

**Main**

```
ipcMain.on('app-message', (event, arg) => {
    switch (arg.event) {
     case 'save-project':
            global.model.data = arg.data;

            switch (arg.sender) {
                case 'editor':
                    timelineWindow.webContents.send('message', { 'event': 'updateData', 'data': global.model.data });
                    break;
                case 'timeline':
                    if (global.appMode != 'player') {
                        editorWindow.webContents.send('message', { 'event': 'updateData', 'data': global.model.data });
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, someone else recommended using the BrowserWindow.id field.  Prior to showing the window, I send a message to the renderer every time a new BrowserWindow is created so that the renderer knows its ID.  The renderer sends its ID on every message and main maintains a Map of ID to Browser Window instances so that it can convert the ID back into a BrowserWindow.